# Openshift, 503 Service Unavailable. No server is available to handle this request

Tags: php, openshift, openshift-cartridge

I have a scalable PHP 5.4 cartridge on Openshift, with a bronze account.
It's a wordpress blog and I've used it until 2 weeks ago.

Today, I returned to visit it and it says:

> 503 Service Unavailable. No server is available to handle this request.

To check the proxy status, I have visited this link http://myapp-mydomain.rhcloud.com/haproxy-status and there I see this:

[image: screenshot]

It seems DOWN.

Checking the logs with rhc tail I see this line:

```
    ==> app-root/logs/haproxy.log <==
[ALERT] 077/194638 (138628) : proxy 'express' has no server available!
[WARNING] 086/161237 (138628) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN for maintenance.
[WARNING] 086/161239 (33522) : config : log format ignored for proxy 'stats' since it has no log address.
[WARNING] 086/161239 (33522) : config : log format ignored for proxy 'express' since it has no log address.
[WARNING] 086/161239 (33522) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN, reason: Layer7 wrong status, code: 500, info: "HTTP status check returned code <3C>500<3E>", check duration: 65ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[ALERT] 086/161239 (33522) : proxy 'express' has no server available!
[WARNING] 086/161240 (33522) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN for maintenance.
[WARNING] 086/161323 (33522) : Server express/local-gear is UP (leaving maintenance).
[WARNING] 086/161325 (33522) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN, reason: Layer7 wrong status, code: 500, info: "HTTP status check returned code <3C>500<3E>", check duration: 237ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[ALERT] 086/161325 (33522) : proxy 'express' has no server available!
```

I've also tried to restart the application using the openshift "restart" button, but it didn't work.

Don't know how to solve. Any idea?

thanks in advance

Comment: Try a complete gear stop then start again.

Comment: Launched 'rhc app stop' but still doesn't work. I think the problem is related to mysql.. here I've explained it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29322474/openshift-cant-connect-to-mysql-from-console can you help me?

Comment: There had been several times my app has stopped working for no apparent reason on openshift. I have had to create a duplicate of the app to see if it was my problem or openshift's. I have run into many openshift bugs. Try creating a duplicate and it might lead you to the problem.   Could this be a memory space problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your free OpenShift gears are handled by unused processing/bandwidth power. If no server is available to run the gears for your app at the moment, the request made would be denied with "503 Service Unavailable: No server is available to handle this request".

If you want to ensure uptime for your app, use paid gears.

Answer (score 0):

This question applies to an older (v2) release of OpenShift Online which is no longer available.  It looks like your app failed to start.

It might be worth trying again using MiniShift, OpenShift Starter, or OpenShift Pro