# Openshift, can't connect to Mysql from console

Tags: mysql, openshift

I'm connected via SSH to my openshift server.
I type: env | grep MYSQL

```
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT=42361
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST=XXXXXXX-mydomain.rhcloud.com
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD=MYPASSWORD
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_PATH_ELEMENT=/opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/bin
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_GEAR_UUID=XXXXXXXXX
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME=MYUSERNAME
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_URL=mysql://MYUSERNAME:MYPASSWORD@XXXXXX-mydomain.rhcloud.com:42361/
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_LD_LIBRARY_PATH_ELEMENT=/opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/lib64
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_GEAR_DNS=XXXXXXX-mydomain.rhcloud.com
```

Then, I run

```
mysql -u $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME -h $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST -P $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT -p
```

and type the exact same password... but I get this error: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'MYUSERNAME'@'10.169.187.123' (using password: YES)

I can't access mysql and my application shows 503 unavailable error (I guess for this reason).

I don't want to lose the data stored inside, so I would like to change password or something.. but since I can't connect to mysql, I can't change the psw like this:

```
\> set password for 'MYUSERNAME'@'10.169.187.123' = PASSWORD('newpassword');
```

Comment: Use the "Contact Us" link at https://help.openshift.com and we'll get this fixed up.  Please reference this Stack Overflow question in your message.

Comment: I already did it. Still waiting after one week.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried accessing the database via the phpMyAdmin page? It should be available under http://.rhcloud.com/phpmyadmin. The credentials for accessing this page are given to you when you create the MySQL cartridge. The default username is 'admin'. If you don't have the admin password anymore, you are of course also out of luck there.

Comment: Hello Hardy, I don't have phpmyadmin installed and if I click on "Add phpMyAdmin 4.0" on the Cartridges page he says me "phpmyadmin-4 cannot be embedded in scalable app". It's very strange this problem...

Comment: @MichDart.. right you can't add phpmyadmon on scalable application..  have you tried simple mysql command on shell?

Comment: Hey @MiyaG, yep. As explained before, I did try to connect using mysql command, but it always give me error.

Comment: It's all explained in the first message. Don't you see it?

Comment: `and type the exact same password... but I get this error: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'MYUSERNAME'@'10.169.187.123' (using password: YES)`.. this is not right way to access you mean you are trying to connect from another domain .

Answer (score 0):

You were so close!
You need to explicitly specify the MySQL password when you connect.

> mysql -u $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME -h $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST -P OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT --password=$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD

Answer (score 0):

I know the post is old, but I had the same issue and @Tadhg's answer was close. So, I have tried the following in the `rhc` environment after connecting to `rhc ssh <APP_NAME>` and it connected me to mysql.

```
mysql -u $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME -h $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST --password=$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD
```

I have to remove the port as it had error on the port, and it worked. I could not use phpMyAdmin as I get error `phpmyadmin-4 cannot be embedded in scalable app ''.

I hope it helps someone, one day. :)